# How to continue the script execution after a background process ending?

Tags: bash, loops, background-process

Good morning

I have this variable

```
NODES="lep1mk17 lep1mk18 lep1mk19"
```

And I am executing this loop (I want to work with parallel processes)

```
56 for i in $NODES
57 do
58        java -jar jmxterm-1.0.1-uber.jar --url <url:port> -i $LOGDIR/$i > $LOGDIR/$i.out &
59        pid-$i=$!
60 done
```

In this case I will have 3 processes in background.

To know when they finish, I use the variable `pid-$i`

At this point I want to stop my script until the background processes ending, so I do:

```
62 for i in $NODES
63 do
64        wait $(pid-$i)
65 done
```

When I execute the script I got some errors:

```
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 59: pid-lep1mk17=30491: command not found
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 59: pid-lep1mk18=30493: command not found
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 59: pid-lep1mk19=30495: command not found
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 64: pid-lep1mk17: command not found
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 64: pid-lep1mk18: command not found
./countMessagesTopicV4.sh: line 64: pid-lep1mk19: command not found
emedina@goku:~/script/kafka$
```

Can someone help me to find my error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names have to be literal, you can't just use an expression as a variable name like you're doing.  (Also variable names can't have `-` in them, but that's a second problem)

bash has associative array variables: you want

```
59: pid[$i]=$!

...

64: wait ${pid[$i]}
```